# Weird problem using JUnit in multi-thread environment

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I meet a weired problem when using JUnit in multi-thread environment. The following code should fail, but it actually pass in eclipse.

```
public class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    private volatile boolean isDone = false;

    public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    fail();
                } finally {
                    isDone = true;
                }
            }
        });

        while (!isDone) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And here'a another piece of code, here I use Future.get() to wait for thread stop, in this case it will fail.

```
public class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    private volatile boolean isDone = false;

    public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Future future=executor.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    fail();
                } finally {
                    isDone = true;
                }
            }
        });

        future.get();
    }
}
```

I googled it and found that JUnit can not handle Multiple-thread unit testing,but what's the differences between these two pieces of code ? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JUnit cannot see the exceptions that occur in threads other than the thread in which the tests are running. In the first case, through an exception occurs by calling `fail`, it occurs in a separate thread run by the `executor`. Hence it is not visible to JUnit and the test passes.

In the second case, the same exception happens in the separate thread run by the `executor` but the exception is effectively "reported back" to the test thread when you call `future.get`. This is because `future.get` throws an `ExecutionException` if the computation of the future failed due to any exception. JUnit is able to see this exception and hence the test fails.

Answer (score 1):

As @abhin4v has pointed out, the exception in the new thread gets swallowed. You could try providing your own `fail`-method that syncronises with the top-level thread very much like in your example with `get()`.

But there's no need to use Futures, just write to a shared variable indicating failure and use `newThreadId.join()`. Apart from that, I'm not aware of any other way of solving this in plain JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDN_EYUvUq0 (starting at 17:09), it explain problems you can get with JUnit and threads.

I think, that in your case, `get()` throws a `ExecutionException` and that's why the second test fails. In the first testcase, jUnit doesn't see the exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the interesting fact that Eclipse and IDEA can spawn a VM in their junit test runners and end up calling system.exit() on it. This means if you don't wait properly in the test (as in the case when you sleep above and hope the the task has completed), it can exit unexpectedly. Interesting, but not exactly what you were asking!

see this [link](http://pequenoperro.blogspot.com/2008/12/junit-and-threaded-tests-i-recently.html) for details...