# why this is not working - Unit testing a synchronous method using parameterized data of Junit?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit, parameterized-unit-test

I am trying to learn the JUnit and wanted to extend it to test in a multi-threaded way.

The class I want to test is PrimeNumberValidator. This just tests if a passed in number is prime or not.

```
package com;

public class PrimeNumberValidator {
    public Boolean validate(final Integer primeNumber) {
        System.out.println("Validating .............:" + primeNumber);
        for (int i = 2; i < (primeNumber / 2); i++) {
            if (primeNumber % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The PrimeNumberValidatorTest is the test class. The 2 of the test data are wrong and I have done this purposely to test for failure. 
The test method testPrimeNumberValidator runs perfectly fine. But, the multi-threaded version 
testMultiThreadedPrimeNumberValidator always says 'pass' for even wrong data. 

Why is this happening like this? 
How do solve this ?

```
package com;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PrimeNumberValidatorTest {
    private Integer primeNumber;
    private Boolean expectedValidation;
    private PrimeNumberValidator primeNumberValidator;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
    primeNumberValidator = new PrimeNumberValidator();
    }

    // Each parameter should be placed as an argument here
    // Every time runner triggers, it will pass the arguments from parameters we defined
    public PrimeNumberValidatorTest(Integer primeNumber, Boolean expectedValidation) {
    this.primeNumber = primeNumber;
    this.expectedValidation = expectedValidation;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection primeNumbers() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { 2, Boolean.FALSE},// 2 is prime so Test should fail
        { 6, Boolean.FALSE}, //is NOT prime so test should pass
        { 19, Boolean.TRUE},//is prime so test should pass
        { 22, Boolean.TRUE} //is NOT prime so test should fail
    });
    }

    // This test will run 4 times since we have 4 parameters defined
    @Test
    public void testPrimeNumberValidator() {
    assertEquals(expectedValidation, primeNumberValidator.validate(primeNumber));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultiThreadedPrimeNumberValidator() {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            assertEquals(expectedValidation, primeNumberValidator.validate(primeNumber));
        }   
        }
    }); 
    }
}
```

Referring to 
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDN_EYUvUq0 as mentioned in one of the posts 
 [Weird problem using JUnit in multi-thread environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039873/weird-problem-using-junit-in-multi-thread-environment), tried as below. 
The exceptions are thrown, but the JUnit does not report failure :(

```
package com;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PrimeNumberValidatorTest {
    volatile Exception exception;
    volatile Error error;

    private Integer primeNumber;
    private Boolean expectedValidation;
    private PrimeNumberValidator primeNumberValidator;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
    primeNumberValidator = new PrimeNumberValidator();
    }

    // Each parameter should be placed as an argument here
    // Every time runner triggers, it will pass the arguments from parameters we defined
    public PrimeNumberValidatorTest(Integer primeNumber, Boolean expectedValidation) {
    this.primeNumber = primeNumber;
    this.expectedValidation = expectedValidation;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection primeNumbers() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { 2, Boolean.FALSE},// 2 is prime so Test should fail
        { 6, Boolean.FALSE}, //is NOT prime so test should pass
        { 19, Boolean.TRUE},//is prime so test should pass
        { 22, Boolean.TRUE} //is NOT prime so test should fail
    });
    }

    // This test will run 4 times since we have 4 parameters defined
    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void testPrimeNumberValidator() {
    assertEquals(expectedValidation, primeNumberValidator.validate(primeNumber));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultiThreadedPrimeNumberValidator() {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            try{
                assertEquals(expectedValidation, primeNumberValidator.validate(primeNumber));
            }catch(Error e){
                System.out.println("error thrown :" + e);
                error =e;
            }catch(Exception e){
                exception=e;
                System.out.println("exception thrown :" + e);
            }
        }   
        }
    }); 
    }

    @After
    public void runAfterEveryTest() throws Exception{
    if(null != error){
        System.out.println("runAfterEveryTest throwing error...............");
        throw error;
    }
    if(null != exception){
        System.out.println("runAfterEveryTest throwing exception...............");
        throw exception;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the multi-threaded is always passing is the following:

- first, the test method does nothing to wait for the multiple threads to complete therefore the `@Test` method is exiting before any errors are reported
- second, the way that testing works is that the assert method throws an exception. The JUnit framework catches this exception by wrapping the `@Test` method and fails the test if an unexpected exception is thrown. However, in the multi-threaded test no exception is thrown from the `@Test` method because they are thrown within the threads and the test method does nothing to check this. One solution for this part would be to use an [ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html)

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved with the below code. The addtion of Future related code made it work.

```
@Test
public void testMultiThreadedPrimeNumberValidator() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    Future future = executor.submit(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try{
                    assertEquals(expectedValidation, primeNumberValidator.validate(primeNumber));
                }catch(Error e){
                    System.out.println("error thrown :" + e);
                    //error =e;
                    System.out.println("error set to :" + e);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("exception thrown :" + e);
                    //exception=e;
                    System.out.println("Exception set to :" + e);
                }
            }   
        }
    }); 
    future.get();
}
```